# Matlab: Plot a line over an image plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a line plot on top of an image plot in Matlab

First I plot the image data

```
figure(1); clf;
imagesc(t); colorbar
hold on;
axis tight
```

and then the line plot

```
line(ysum,y,'Color','red')
hold off;
```

The line plot however deletes the image and sets the background to white.
How can I plot on top of the image?

Comment: It is possible that `ysum` or `y` are locations outside the image domain, causing axis limits change. You likely have large values in one of those, and end up with a tiny image in a corner of the plot. However, please see [mre], without it your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't wrong, but it is not a minimal reproducible example, since you haven't defined `t, y, ysum`. When you call `imagesc(t)` the rows and columns will be the indices of `t`. In other words, it is the same as calling `imagesc([1, size(t,2)], [1, size(t,1)], t)`. If `t` is small (say 10 x 10) but the elements of `y,ysum` are large (e.g. > 1000) then the 10 x 10 image will still be there, but it will be squished into the corner. Almost invisible.

So you need to make sure that the range of `y, ysum, t` line up. A quick work-around:

```
xidx = [min(ysum), max(ysum)];
yidx = [min(y), max(y)];
imagesc(xidx, yidx, t);
```

Comment: My answer is the same as the first comment, but i posted before i saw it!

Comment: Indeed the problem is the large value in the ysum vector. This solves the problem: `ysum = sum(t,2);
ysum = ysum/max(ysum(:))*100;`